# Unable to remove references to UIWebView from IOS Builds. (Xcode 11.5, Swift 5)

Tags: uiwebview

Warning! I am beginner.

Apple testflight is refusing to accept any builds of a previously healthy project, sending out this message;
*

> TMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no
> longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and
> reliability. Learn more

- 

OK, I understand that the UIWebView is now fully deprecated and no longer allowed.

I have scoured all the files in may app manually using the Xcode editor and find there is no reference to the deprecated string ( UIWebView ) in any file that I can edit.
Using the Xcode "find in project" tool also says it's not there.

If I build & archive, then run grep in CLI to examine the resulting package contents, the report is that the string "UIWebView" IS found in the app and the dSYM file.

Also, again using grep, I have examined the various framework files referenced in the editor, the report is that framework 'UIKIT' contains many references to UIWebView. The check does not reveal any other references to the string.
UIKIT is still shown as required in the build list.

I have cleaned the project, deleted all derived data, closed and opened the project and xcode.

Could any kind soul point me in the right direction here - I am stumped.

Thanks, Max

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

After learning a lot more, I found it was the PayPal external framework which had deprecated references in it. They no longer maintain it. I had to remove that and I added Braintree instead which is kept updated.

I had failed to check the external frameworks when trying to sanitise the cause. There is no magic bullet here...I just had to plod through all the components.

This was mostly caused by my inexperience and failure to understand the function of the various components of an app.